# Project Euler Problem 213 (continued...)

Tags: self-study, monte-carlo, markov-process, computational-statistics

This question is a continuation of
[How should one approch Project Euler problem 213 ("Flea Circus")?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2427/how-should-one-approch-project-euler-problem-213-flea-circus)

I followed the approach of Glen_b outlined in his
answer in the page referenced above. I am using Java.

So now I am at a point where I think I have correctly calculated the probabilities `p[30][30]`
where `p[i][j]` denotes the probability of the `(i,j)` square being empty after these 50 steps
(1 step = 1 ring bell) from the problem statement.

Now I am treating these 900 numbers from the `p` array as describing 900 random variables.

So I start doing a Monte Carlo simulation.
For now I am doing `N = 60 000 000` such tests/experiments.

In a single experiment I loop through the `p` array, and I generate one random number `x`
in `[0,1)` for each `(i,j)` couple. I use this number `x` and the probability `p[i][j]`
to generate a boolean value `0/1` which says if the square is empty or not.

Then I count how many empty squares I got in all my `N` tests.
And then I divide this number by the number `900*N`.
This should give me the Monte-Carlo approximated answer.

But my problem is that I think I am too far away from the precision that is needed.
Why? Because I then run another `N` such experiments.

And the answers I get in the 1st set of `N` experiments compared to the
answer in the 2nd set of `N` experiments differ by way too much
(they differ in the 4th or even in the 3rd sign after the decimal dot).

I wonder why. Aren't 60 million tests good/many enough?

If not (i.e. if I need more experiments), and if I am so far away as it seems then...
How can I finish solving this problem in reasonable runtime, given that I have already
the matrix `p` with the probabilities.

Or maybe... I am not doing the Monte-Carlo simulation quite right
( though I doubt that because I am getting already some answers like `330.7xxxxxxx`
so I am obviously on the right track i.e. I do not have any major logical bugs).

I am not sure.

Any help/guidance (about how to finish the solution from here) would be much appreciated.

Comment: i agree with Andy W's comment after Glen's answer.  You aren't answering the same question.

Comment: @MohammadAthar Yes, but there's another comment that one can from that probability matrix compute the expected number of empty cells.

Comment: My answer to the thread you reference, as well as an answer by Xi'an (who did an efficient simulation with $10^8$ iterations), anticipated and answered your questions.

Comment: @whuber Well, I don't in full understand Xi'an's answer. So I was hoping someone to write in plainer words or in other words how one can go on from the point where I am... But since my question is closed now I guess that won't happen.

Comment: Anyway thanks I will think some more and see what I can do myself from here

Comment: Wow, I solved it finally and the program runs instantly too. Turns out the only additional step I needed was just to sum up the 900 values in this `p` array. That gives the `precise` answer. That Monte-Carlo simulation that I was doing previously (once having the `p` array) was not needed at all.

Comment: @whuber But for the sake of preciseness... my question is definitely not a duplicate of the question I am referring to. Thanks anyway.